# linux fork - execl, the executed process becomes zombie

Tags: c++, linux, fork, zombie-process

I'm trying to run twinkle command line from a child process.
For example like this:

```
int hangup() {
write_on_display("line3", "            ");
write_on_display("hide_icon", "DIALTONE");
write_on_display("hide_icon", "BACKLIGHT");

int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    int res = execl("/usr/bin/twinkle", " ", "--immediate", "--cmd",
            "answerbye", (char *) NULL);
    _exit(0);
} else {
    perror("hangup");
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

but twinkle becomes zombie:

```
10020 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10040 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10053 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10064 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10097 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10108 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
10130 pts/1    Z+     0:00 [twinkle] <defunct>
```

I tried to set 
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); 
but without success.
Actually I think that the child process dies, before twinkle had finished.

Running twinkle from command line like:

```
twinkle --immediate --call 100
```

does not make zombie - twinkle closes  properly.
What I'm missing there?

Answer (score 7):

The parent process needs to call [`waitpid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) with process id of the child. From the linked reference page:

> All of these system calls are used to wait for state changes in a child of the calling process, and obtain information about the child whose state has changed. A state change is considered to be: the child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a signal. **In the case of a terminated child, performing a wait allows the system to release the resources associated with the child; if a wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains in a "zombie" state** (see NOTES below).

For example:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (0 == pid)
{
    /* Child process. */
}
else
{
    /* Parent process, wait for child to complete. */
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: IIRC, the code after `execl` will *not* be executed unless `execl` produces an error.

Comment: @Jite, correct. The `exit(0);` _disappears_ if `execl()` is successful.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but I need parent and child to work asynchronous.

Actually I found my mistake.
So, if somebody have similar problem, with a signal handler function like this:

```
void catch_child(int sig_num)
{
    /* when we get here, we know there's a zombie child waiting */
    int child_status;

    wait(&child_status);

}
```

and 
    signal(SIGCHLD, catch_child)

in the main() function
everything works.

PP
Here: 
  [is a very good explanation.](http://www.academictutorials.com/ipc/ipc-process-creation.asp)

Comment: That is a good idea to catch the "child process end" signal in the parent process, and to `wait` for it there. Does it really work?